# Multiple Markers GMaps PHP SQLSERVER

Tags: php, sql-server, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've created the following code to show me some markers on GMaps. If i delete the code

```
var locations = [
<?=implode(',',$locations); // De in PHP gemaakte array samenvoegen tot een regel gescheiden door komma's ?>
```

];

the Gmaps shows up.

If i add the code the page returns blank. Main goal is to run a query which results into a  lat/lng information. That information had the create a marker on GMaps

Complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Agents</title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=AIzaSyBPjiZ-mcRgK6jV00orSHefk6L40gsznkk&sensor=false&language=nl&region=nl"></script>
      <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
  <?php
 include ("dblogin.php")
// Alle klanten ophalen
$query = "SELECT MachineId as name, [value17] as lat ,[value18] as lng, ast.online as state FROM [ksubscribers].[dbo].[vAuditMachineSummary] left join ksubscribers.dbo.agentState as ast on ast.agentGuid = vAuditMachineSummary.agentGuid where [value17] is not null";
$data = mssql_query($query);


// Door alle klanten lopen
while($row = mssql_fetch_array($data))
{
    // Een array opbouwen met de klant naam en coördinaten
    // (welke nog even van een komma naar een punt veranderd worden)
    $location[] = '['.$row['name'].'","'.($row['lat']).'","'.($row['lng']).'"","'.($row['state']).']';

}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

// De array met gegevens in Javascript
var locations = [
    <?=implode(',',$locations); // De in PHP gemaakte array samenvoegen tot een regel gescheiden door komma's ?>
];


// Nieuwe cq mooiere visuele weergave gebruiken
google.maps.visualRefresh = true;

// Functie die aangesproken wordt zodra de pagina geladen is
function initialize()
{
    // Kaart opties
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.23, 4.55), // Coördinaten van centraal Nederland
        zoom: 8, // Inzoomen zodat Nederland goed zichtbaar is
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP // De wegenkaart gebruiken
    };

    // Kaart laden in div met het ID map-canvas
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapOptions);

    // De "markers" plaatsen
    setMarkers(map,locations);
}

 // De array met gegevens in Javascript
//var loc = [
 //   <?php=implode(',',$location);?>
//];

// Functie die de "markers" plaatst op de kaart
function setMarkers(map,locations)
{
    // De afbeelding voor de klanten op de kaart
    var image = 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons-land/vista-people/24/Office-Customer-Male-Light-icon.png';

    // Door alle klanten lopen
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
    {
        // De coördinaten ophalen
        var loc = locations[i];
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(loc[1], loc[2]);

        // De "marker" plaatsen
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            icon: image,
            title: loc[0]
        });
    }
}

// Zodra de pagina is geladen de initialize functie aanspreken
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

(Not tested) The problem most likely is this line:

```
$location[] = '['.$row['name'].'","'.($row['lat']).'","'.($row['lng']).'"","'.($row['state']).']';
```

Here you close a string after $row['name'] which you never opened.

Also take a note to the PHP-function json_encode (https://www.php.net/json_encode), this one ensures you valid javascript (if $row['name'] for example contains a "-character).

Comment: how do you mean? i saw some strange things and changed it into
`$locations[] = '['.$row['name'].'","'.$row['lat'].'","'.$row['lng'].'"","'.$row['state'].']';`


but the page still stays blank.

Comment: if $row['name'] equals "Sander" (without quotes), the complete string (after concatenation) will be: 
`[Sander", "123", "456"", "state]`
Which is invalid javascript

Comment: Hello Peter,
There was something wrong with the string you said. Changed it into `$location[] = '["'.$row['name'].'", '.$row['lat'].', '.$row['lng'].', '.$row['state'].']';`

There was also a sql connection problem. Installed the SQL Drivers again.

Thanx

Comment: Are you aware of what would happen if $row['name'] itself contains a "-character?

Comment: No im not :). im not very familiar with this content.

Comment: Well, write down for yourself what `'["'.$row['name'].'", '.$row['lat']...` would look like if $row['name'] equals [`evil " atacker`] and try to understand why that isn't valid javascript. If you don't see it, write down below what you came up with.

Comment: could you provide me an example Peter?

Comment: i figured it out. followed the Google example.